# I'd like to have https:// automatically attached to the link

Tags: flutter, dart, web

When I tried to retrieve img from the website, the link started with /upload/.... instead of https://.

I want to have https:// written automatically in front of me. What should I do?

homepage:

```
<div class="photo_list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/yongwon-h/na/ntt/selectNttInfo.do?nttSn=85189591&amp;mi=73747">

                <img src="/upload/bbs/files/2021/hgschl/yongwon-h/ntt/62865/ntt_85189591/thumb/thumb_img_9028b523-7bfb-466f-848c-65870a93b99c1616411595463.jpg" onerror="this.src='/images/co/na/noImg.gif'" alt="대표이미지">
                                                            
                <p>책을 가까이, 책은 나의 친구!! 아침독서의 생활화!!!</p>
                <span>
                                                
                    2021.03.22
                    <br> 조회   6
                </span>
                
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

MY CODE:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_share/flutter_share.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_animations/flutter_staggered_animations.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class UpdatePost extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UpdatePostState createState() => _UpdatePostState();
}

class _UpdatePostState extends State<UpdatePost> {
  List<String> title = List();
  List<String> post = List();
  List<String> link = List();

  List<String> image = List();

  void _getDataFromWeb() async {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(
        'http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/yongwon-h/na/ntt/selectNttList.do?mi=73747&&bbsId=62865');
    final response = await http.get(uri);
    dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
    final link2 = document.getElementsByClassName('photo_list');
    final content = document.getElementsByClassName('photo_list');
    final elements = document.getElementsByClassName('photo_list');

    final ImageElement = document.getElementsByClassName('photo_list');
    setState(() {
      title = elements
          .map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHtml)
          .toList();
      post = content
          .map((element) => element.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHtml)
          .toList();
      link = link2
          .map((element) =>
              element.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].attributes['href'])
          .toList();

      image = ImageElement.map((element) =>
          element.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].attributes['src']).toList();
    });
  }

  Future<void> share(dynamic link, String title) async {
    await FlutterShare.share(
        title: 'Codding Application',
        text: title,
        linkUrl: link,
        chooserTitle: 'Where You Want to Share');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getDataFromWeb();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      body: post.length == 0
          ? Text("No data", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: post.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                  position: index,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 375),
                  child: SlideAnimation(
                      child: FadeInAnimation(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      dynamic url = link[index];
                      if (await canLaunch(url))
                        launch(url);
                      else {
                        print('error');
                      }
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Card(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.black87,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                child: Image.network(
                                  image[index],
                                  scale: 0.1,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Text(
                                  title[index],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 15),
                              Text(
                                post[index],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  FlatButton(
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      share(link[index], title[index]);
                                    },
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Share With Friends",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                                  FlatButton(
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      dynamic url = link[index];
                                      if (await canLaunch(url))
                                        launch(url);
                                      else {
                                        print('error');
                                      }
                                    },
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Explore Post",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))),
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

conclusion:
I want to automatically put http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr in front of the called tag a.

I feel like I'm asking repeatedly, but I really don't know. I googled thousands of sites in a week. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:wnetworking/wnetworking.dart';

final Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> reDic = {
  'notices' : {
    'relPath' : '/yongwon-h/main.do',
    're' : <RegExp>[
      RegExp(r'<h2 class="tit_1">(.|\n|\r|\u2028|\u2029)*?<h2 class="tit_2">'),
      RegExp(r'<li><a.+>(.+)<\/a>(.|\n|\r|\u2028|\u2029)*?(\d{4}\.\d\d\.\d\d)'),
    ]
  },
  'images' : {
    'relPath' : '/yongwon-h/na/ntt/selectNttList.do?mi=73747&&bbsId=62865',
    're' : <RegExp>[
      RegExp(r'<div class="photo_list">(.|\n|\r|\u2028|\u2029)*?<!-- \/\/게시판 리스트'),
      RegExp(r'<img src="(.+)" onerror'),
    ]
  },
};


class Yongwon {
  static const _baseUrl = 'http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr';

  static FutureOr<void> fetchNoticies() async {
    await _getHTMLObjects(
        reDic['notices']!['relPath'], 
        reDic['notices']!['re']![0],
        reDic['notices']!['re']![1],
      )
      .then((matches) {
        if (matches != null) {
          matches.forEach((match) => print('${match.group(1)} ..... ${match.group(3)}'));
        }
      });
  }
  
  static FutureOr<void> fetchImages() async {
    await _getHTMLObjects(
        reDic['images']!['relPath'], 
        reDic['images']!['re']![0],
        reDic['images']!['re']![1],
      )
      .then((matches) {
        if (matches != null) {
          matches.forEach((match) => print('$_baseUrl${match.group(1)}'));
        }
      });
  }

  static Future<Iterable<RegExpMatch>?> _getHTMLObjects(String relPath, RegExp reContainer, RegExp reObjects) async {
    var page = await NetService.getRaw(_baseUrl + relPath)
      .whenComplete(() => print('Page done.\n'));

    if (page != null) {
      final objectsPane = reContainer.firstMatch(page)!.group(0);
      if (objectsPane != null) {
        return Future.value(reObjects.allMatches(objectsPane));
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  await Yongwon.fetchImages();
  print('\nJob done!');
}
```

Netservice (partial code):

```
class NetService {
  static Future<String?> getRaw(String url, {int okCode = 200}) {
    return http.get(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((response) {
        if (response.statusCode == okCode) {
          return response.body;
        }
        PrintService.showDataNotOK(response);
        return null;
      })
      .catchError((err) => PrintService.showError(err));
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Page done.

http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/upload/bbs/files/2021/hgschl/yongwon-h/ntt/62865/ntt_85189591/thumb/thumb_img_9028b523-7bfb-466f-848c-65870a93b99c1616411595463.jpg
http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/upload/bbs/files/2021/hgschl/yongwon-h/ntt/62865/ntt_85169237/thumb/thumb_img_0fe7d01b-6941-4468-8623-088af971fbf21616047569744.jpg
http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/upload/bbs/files/2021/hgschl/yongwon-h/ntt/62865/ntt_85148970/thumb/thumb_img_67ae1c34-cd49-4af4-8a68-cacec672c84d1615859096270.jpg
http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/upload/bbs/files/2021/hgschl/yongwon-h/ntt/62865/ntt_85041266/thumb/thumb_img_ddc5097b-ae4e-4190-b0b8-1aa88cf78e491614223854604.jpg
http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/upload/bbs/files/2021/hgschl/yongwon-h/ntt/62865/ntt_85039068/thumb/thumb_img_f5c77ec4-a448-44b0-b5b1-61079be18eb61614145925749.jpg
http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/upload/bbs/files/2021/hgschl/yongwon-h/ntt/62865/ntt_85002051/thumb/thumb_img_0df44e4d-9872-4605-a94f-32b3004bc42a1612331543446.jpg
http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/upload/bbs/files/2021/hgschl/yongwon-h/ntt/62865/ntt_84955511/thumb/thumb_img_de1fc864-2689-4917-85bc-b5d714040b1f1610248949513.jpg
http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/upload/bbs/files/2021/hgschl/yongwon-h/ntt/62865/ntt_84950100/thumb/thumb_img_cd3270ee-7bd0-4601-81fc-2de446903e281609919353000.jpg
http://yongwon-h.gne.go.kr/upload/bbs/files/2021/hgschl/yongwon-h/ntt/62865/ntt_84950096/thumb/thumb_img_0eee718a-a2de-4182-a0d9-f97de17d98741609919173296.jpg

Job done!
```

Comment: Thank you for your help again!
But could you revise the answer and write NetService.getRaw, too?

Comment: Code added... it is the most basic operation for that class. Which answer should I review?